# Laravel 5 - change default login action

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.0 built-in authentication controllers. However, I'd like to add some actions during login besides authenticating, for example updating another table. I can't seem to find where I should write such code, though.

For registration I added what I wanted in the file "Registrar.php" under the folder "Services". How can I do that for Login?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can put following function in `AuthController.php` to override default function from `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait. And you can change it as per your need.

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                ]);
}
```

Comment: Copying code from a trait is not the best option. Authentication logic in the trait might change in future versions and it won't be reflected in your code. Laravel fires events when users get authenticated and those should be used to separate auth logic from additional actions that need to be run.

Comment: See an example usage of authentication events in the answer

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Agreed. I completely forgot about events. Events are better place to hook in your code. up voted.

Comment: @pinkalvansia thanks for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Laravel's** authentiction layer fires multiple event when different authentication-related actions happen:

- **auth.attempt** - when user tries to authenticate
- **auth.login** - when user authenticates successfully
- **auth.logout** - when user logouts

You can listen for those events (**auth.login** in your case) and apply necessary actions without copying a code from a trait, that would make you update the code manually if some changes happen to how authentication works.

First, you need to create a listener class:

```
class AuthLoginHandler {
  public function handle(User $user, $remember) {
    // do whatever you need to do after user authenticates
  }
}
```

Then register the listener in your **EventServiceProvider** class:

```
protected $listen = [
  'auth.login' => [
        AuthLoginHandler::class
    ],
];
```

Your handler's **handle()** method will be now called every time user authenticates, even if you have multiple login forms for different user types or even some other forms of authentications than a form.

You can read more about events in Laravel here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#defining-listeners

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. Where should I place that listener class? Any specific laravel folder ?

Comment: Anywhere you like, as long as the namespace matches directory structure so that it can be autoloaded. In the docs they put listeners in app/Listeners, so you can do the same

Comment: Any ideas why the `AuthLoginHandler@handle` method is not fired upon login? I did everything as described in answer but method doesn't execute after login. I hope I'm missing something basic here. (Laravel 5.2)